# In SharePoint 13 where do I go to enable Tags?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, tags

I am using SharePoint 13. Where do I go to enable the Tags option?

Comment: are you on sharepiont on prem or Office 365?

Comment: My SharePoint 13 Administrator said we are using the Office 365 version. What do you mean by prem... Premium?  Also, what is meant by "site collection?" I'm guessing that the Tags is enabled via Office 365.

Comment: Correction. I was just told we are NOT using Office 365. I will get the details soon. I was also told SharePoint 13 did away with Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags and notes feature is retired in SharePoint Online( office 365) couple of years back.

Here's what we recommend as an alternative to Tags & Notes:

- Follow documents to see updates in your newsfeed when others make
  changes to the document ([see Follow documents to track them](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Follow-documents-to-track-them-e022c55c-4bf0-4809-8b3a-1da870cf17d7) )
- Keep track of all the documents and sites relevant to you ( see
  [Organize documents and sites in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Organize-documents-and-sites-in-Office-365-1a36030f-3e54-4c43-8401-b7bcd0d1c16b))
- Add an enterprise keyword to a SharePoint item to use for
  distributing the item to anyone following the keyword (see [Add an
  enterprise keywords column to a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-list-or-library-314ce556-e4bf-4ef7-9939-6a1bedfc434a))
- Use Yammer (see [Say hello to Yammer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Say-hello-to-Yammer-02ac514e-cf1d-4060-9cde-6038ca812ede))
- Review differences between SharePoint newsfeed and Yammer (see [Pick
  your enterprise social network: Yammer or Newsfeed?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Pick-your-enterprise-social-network-Yammer-or-Newsfeed-21954c85-4384-47d4-96c2-dfa1c9d56e66))
- Add a Yammer feed to a SharePoint page (see [Embed a Yammer feed into
  a SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-a-Yammer-feed-into-a-SharePoint-site-4817d2fa-50f6-4f25-88a0-a312745768d4))

[SharePoint Online Tags & Notes feature retired](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-Tags-Notes-feature-retired-77851BD5-6D5E-42FE-9BF6-D7C17EEB771F)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. By the way, I was just told we are not using Office 365. He said he gave me the wrong info.  The Admin will get that info to me soon.  Do any of these directions change if that's the case?

Comment: yes it will change, becuase on prem if you have the managed meta data service then you can use it. i would open another question with specific information so that we get the right answer there